# JAVA: Pruning a Decision Tree

Tags: java, binary-tree, decision-tree, pruning

I'm writing a function that is supposed to prune a decision tree. The function should remove any nodes in the tree whose "Instance array length" is less than a given input length (this decision tree holds nodes who hold an array of values). My problem (I think) is that passing node references to this method and then assigning null to any nodes within the function does not remove these nodes globally. It simply removes the local reference. Here is the code I have written:

```
private void pruneRecursively(DTNode crt, int l){
    if(crt.a.length < l){
        removeSubNodes(crt);
    }

    else{
        if(crt.left != null) //if current node has a left child
            pruneRecursively(crt.left, l);
        if(crt.right != null) //if current node has a right child
            pruneRecursively(crt.right, l);
    }
}


private void removeSubNodes(DTNode crt)
    if(crt.left != null)
        removeSubNodes(crt.left);
    if(crt.right != null)
        removeSubNodes(crt.right);

    //crt.a = null;
    crt = null;
```

How can I write this code differently so that any node whose Instance array length is less than input length l is completely removed from the tree?

***EDIT***
Here's the header of the node class. It seems like relevant info:

```
public class DTNode {
    Instance[] a; //array of instance variables
    double testValue; //determines where to split data
    DTNode left, right; //each node links to two child nodes
```

Answer (score 0):

Your 'crt' parameter is reference to the original object. Thus you essentially are nullifying that reference.

I think you need to nullify it in context of holding object (not within recursive function). More specifically in method 'pruneRecursively' instead of calling:

```
removeSubNodes(crt);
```

I would just call something like:

```
crt.left = null;
crt.right = null;
```

Hope it helps,
Best regards!